# How could I extract the lengthy config from my controller/main code

Tags: python

In my `controller.py` file, I have lots of actions to do.

And I also need the following config in dictionary format.

But these configs,  `params_template`, `header`, .... are really distracting  me.

How could I save them in another Python file , and load them into current `controller.py`

Thanks

```
  params_template="""
   {
    "__EVENTTARGET": "AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$LinkButtonSubmit",
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SalesCode": null,
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations[0].DepartureStationCode": FROM_CITY,
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations[0].ArrivalStationCode": TO_CITY,
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations[0].DepartureDate": "11/28/2015",
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations[1].DepartureStationCode": null,
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations[1].ArrivalStationCode": null,
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations[1].DepartureDate": null,
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.Direction": "Oneway",
    "fromDate": "1448640000000",
    "returnDate": null,
    "fromDate_1": null,
    "fromDate_2": null,
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.AdultCount": "1",
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.ChildrenCount": "0",
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.InfantCount": "0",
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.PromoCode": null
  }
  """

  headers = {
      'Origin': 'http://www.flyscoot.com',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
      'Referer': 'http://www.flyscoot.com/index.php/en/',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH': 'AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3',
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a separate configuration file from the data you have. For example,
in a file `test.ini`, store your data like below:

```
[headers]
Origin: 'http://www.flyscoot.com'
Accept-Encoding: 'gzip, deflate'
Accept-Language: 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: '1'
User-Agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'
Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
Cache-Control: 'max-age=0'
Referer: 'http://www.flyscoot.com/index.php/en/'
Connection: 'keep-alive'
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: 'AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3'
```

Once you are done, you can now use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) to achieve a very flexible  control on your data.

If you apply the below code with above data, see what you can achieve:

```
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser

parser= RawConfigParser()
parser.read('demo.ini')

print 
#To retrieve all the sections 
print parser.sections()

print
#to retrieve options of a section
print parser.options('headers')

#To get value of each option in a section
for i in parser.options('headers'):
     print parser.get('headers',i)
```

Output:

```
['headers']

['origin', 'accept-encoding', 'accept-language', 'upgrade-insecure-requests', 'user-agent', 'content-type', 'accept', 'cache-control', 'referer', 'connection', 'alexatoolbar-alx_ns_ph']

'http://www.flyscoot.com'
'gzip, deflate'
'en-US,en;q=0.8'
'1'
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
'max-age=0'
'http://www.flyscoot.com/index.php/en/'
'keep-alive'
'AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3'
```

Read more about ConfigParser from [Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples). Hope this helps :)